# Making a jquery carousel from scratch

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing

I know there are a ton of questions on here about jquery image carousel, but they all refer to a plugin. I would like to make one from scratch. It's a pretty simple one, there are 2 buttons, one left and one right. when you click the left button, the position of the overall container that has all the images shifts to the left, and the right makes it go right.

This is what I have so far... Right now the problem is only the left button works. (the right button works only once you slide the image to the left once) And I also want it to animate across all the images, and go to the last image when you get to the end of the set of images

JS:

```
total_entries = $("image-entry").length;
var current_index = 0;
var slider_entries = $('#slider-entries');

$('#home-slider #left').click(function(){
    go_to_index(current_index-1);
    return false;
});

$('#home-slider #right').click(function(){
    go_to_index(current_index+1);
    return false;
});



var go_to_index = function(index){
    if(index < 0)
        index = total_entries - 1;
    if(index > total_entries - 1)
        index = 0;
    if(current_index == index)
        return;



    var left_offset = -1 * index * 720;
    slider_entries.stop().animate({"left": left_offset}, 250);
    //description_container.stop().animate({"left":left_offset}, 250);
    current_index = index;
};
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="slider-entries">
        <div class="image-entry">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/720/230" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-entry">
            <img src="http://placedog.com/720/230" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-entry">
            <img src="http://placedog.com/720/230" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

total width of each image is 720px
total with of slider-entries is

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with the total_entries variable.
First of all you need a "var" in front, to define that it's a new variable.
Second, you forgot a "." (dot) to search for the class in your HTML code..

your first line should be:

```
var total_entries = $(".image-entry").length;
```

Hope it works ;-)

Comment: AHH yes it worked thanks :) I don't know how i could have missed that. sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes

Comment: Know the feeling - spend almost half a day last week getting my script working in IE because I forgot the "var" which is crucial for javascript stuff to work in IE ;-)